# How to reply to an unofficial offer from my second choice when I also have an unofficial offer from my first choice?

Tags: job-search, postdocs, biology

Here is my situation. I am looking for a post-doc position. I have two choices, A and B.

My first choice is A. And I already got an un-official offer from A. I was told that A is working on a official offer. But I haven't got the official offer yet.

Now, my second choice, B, also send me an email. B tells me that he would like to give me an offer if I am interested in joining his lab. How should I reply? Is it appropriate to tell him that I am interested?

Answer (score 2):

If you're interested in both, then email each of them and say so.

If you don't have the formal offer then you don't have the job and shouldn't make decisions without it.

Comment: "shouldn't make decisions without it."  Considering the slow pace of university bureaucracy, that is not always possible.

Comment: Related: [How secure is a post doc job offer in an email from the department chair prior to receiving the official written letter?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/65145/how-secure-is-a-post-doc-job-offer-in-an-email-from-the-department-chair-prior-t)

Answer (score 1):

IMO- Tell the 2nd professor guy B, in your own words, that you are very curious about what the offer is, and that you are awaiting a separate offer from another professor.